# Django Query Set Complex Find

Tags: mysql, django

I am looking to solve this optimally using Django Query Set.

Each library can have one and only one book.
Several libraries can have multiple instances of the same book (i.e.: Library1 can have an instance of "Girl with the Dragon Tattoo" and Library4 can have another instance of "Girl with the Dragon Tattoo")

```
Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

Library(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)    # multiple libraries have the book
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So how would I find a book that is in less than 3 libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `annotate` and `Count`.

```
 Book.objects.annotate(n_libraries=Count('library')).filter(n_libraries__lt=3)
```

Comment: this seems to work except will Count('library') return the count of all libraries or the count of libraries that have that instance of the book... I don't want a count of all libraries, just the ones that have that book

Comment: This will return the count of libraries that have that instance of the book. Think of it like this, in addition to the normal info a Book has, this will annotate the result with the # of libraries who have that book. Each book in the resulting QuerySet will have its own #.